# Display BLOB images in Play 1.2.4 Framework

Tags: postgresql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am doing this project where I have to store a user's information including his image.
I'm storing it in the database as a blob image.
IF "photo" is my column for images, than when i render other columns in the webpage , for eg : "render.column_name" it works fine. But when i do it for images, like "render.photo", the DB returns something as "jpa.blob....." in my web page. Can someone help me how to display this image stored in the DB?

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate controller method to supply the image data. The controller could look like this, assuming you have some meta-information about the file, namely, the mime-type, here in a custom entity `FileStore`.

```
public class ShowFile extends Controller {
    public static void render(String id) {
        FileStore fs = // fetch the file out of the DB  using the id

        notFoundIfNull(fs);

        response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(fs.mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
        renderBinary(new ByteArrayInputStream(fs.content), fs.content.length);
    }
}
```

In the page you'll link to that method using the `img` tag:

```
<img src="@{ShowFile.render(image.id)}" />
```